# Bash check arg value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script where I pass a string variable.
Now I would like to check the value of the variable passed like this:

1. Check if it's not null
2. Check if is "Test1"
3. Check if is "Test2"

I wrote this:
#!/bin/bash

```
if [[ "$1" == "" || "$1" != "Test1" || "$1" != "Test2" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: no argument or bad argument passed. Only Test1 or Test2 is accepted"
    exit 2
else
    echo "ok good value"
    exit 0
fi
```

but when I try the script (./script.sh Test1 or ./script.sh Test2) I receive always:

> ERROR: no argument or bad argument passed. Only Test1 or Test2 is
> accepted

Comment: if argument is null __OR__ argument is __NOT__ `Test1` __OR__ argument is __NOT__ Test2 is always going to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your support, but it's wrong, because accept all values not null.

I solved using this:

```
if [[ "$1" != "Test1" ]] && [[ "$1" != "Test2" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `if [[ ...`, try `case` which is more portable:

```
case "$1" in 
    Test[12]) echo "ok good value"
              exit ;;
    *)        echo "ERROR: no argument or bad argument passed. Only Test1 or Test2 is accepted";
              exit 2 ;;
esac
```

---

Note:  if a program has *many* users vague error messages of the form *"No X or else no Y"* can sometimes waste man-years of collective time, because half the users will be testing for the wrong problem.  So if the code had a lot of users, separate error messages would be better:

```
case "$1" in 
    Test[12]) echo "ok good value"
              exit ;;
    "")       echo "ERROR: no argument passed. Only Test1 or Test2 is accepted";
              exit 2 ;;
    *)        echo "ERROR: Bad argument, only Test1 or Test2 is accepted";
              exit 2 ;;
esac
```

Comment: `exit 0` would still be preferable. `exit` by itself uses the exit status of `echo`, which *should* be 0 but could be non-zero under some circumstances.

Comment: @chepner, The omission was intentional.  It's not obvious what circumstances might occur where plain old `echo` would fail in some way where it wouldn't be better to know that it failed.  For example:  `echo foo > /; echo $?` prints a "1", and that is useful -- especially for a novice...

Comment: If you're going to flag an error with writing to standard output, you should be consistent. If the exit status is 2, was the problem with the arguments, or did *that* `echo` fail for some reason?

Comment: @chepner, Agreed that we don't want ambiguous error codes.  But your last example assumes it's even possible for a plain `echo "string"` to return an exit status of 2.   If there's a good example of that, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```sh
if [[ "$1" == "" || "$1" != "Test1" || "$1" != "Test2" ]]; then
```

with

```sh
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "$1" == "Test1" ] || [ "$1" == "Test2" ]]; then
```

Comment: This *allows* an empty argument.